# Doubly Linked List - Java

Tags: java, list, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Is it possible to create a Doubly Linked List in Java with two elements. One element has to be String where as the other one has to be Int.

Is this possible and if so How?

Thanks

Comment: Yes.  Yes, it is possible.  Do you need each element to contain a String and Integer, or is it a mixed-type list (one element is String, another element is Object)?

Comment: Each element should contain a String and that String should be assigned a Integer value.

Comment: So it's not really a String and an Integer object; it's a String with a value that can be interpreted as an Integer then, right?

Comment: I guess so. But the String needs to be assigned a specific value.

Comment: It would aid your question if you provided examples of your expected input.  I'm only shooting in the dark here, but it sounds like you need a holder object to place into the linked list.  Do you also need to create the linked list yourself?  This will alter the answers below.

Comment: Input such as "Football" and the value 11. And "Cricket" with 5  to be assigned to it. And if I call Football and Cricket it should output something like "Football and Cricket = 16".

Comment: It sounds like you want each element to be a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: Maybe he wants a wrapper object with fields String and Integer, which can be placed in to LL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
list.add(new String("Hello"));
list.add(new Integer(42));
```

**EDIT:** Updated according to OP's comments:

First create a class that will keep a `String` and an `int`:

```
public class ListNode {

   public String stringValue;

   public int integerValue;

   public ListNode(String s, int i) {
       this.stringValue = s;
       this.integerValue = i;
   }
}
```

Then add them to a `LinkedList`:

```
LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
list.add(new ListNode("Hello", 42));
list.add(new ListNode("Testing", 5));
```

**Alternatively:**

You can do it in a simpler way using an implementation of the `Map` interface (e.g. `HashMap`) and associate strings to integers like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
myMap.put("Hello", 42);
myMap.put("Testing", 5);
System.out.println(myMap.get("Hello")); // will print 42
System.out.println(myMap.get("Hello") + myMap.get("Testing")); // will print 47
```

Comment: I mean for example assign the 42 to the "Hello" element?

Comment: Do you mean to assign the `"Hello"` element another `String` with the value `"42"`?

Comment: If i call upon the "Hello" from the list it should come up with the value 42. If there is different String such as "Testing" that will be assigned a different value such as 5.

Comment: I see. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Me Again.... I've created the linked list But does anyone know how to call upon the int value? eg I need to add the 42 stored in "Hello" with the 5 stored in "Testing" and display the answer?

Comment: The last line in my example does that, doesn't it? It displays 47.

Comment: If it is not what you are looking for, post your problem as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

[`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is doubly linked list implementation in java, You can have it for any object type wrapping your required fields